# Selecting file names beginning with "NVH" and not "NVHE" in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to select files names beginning with NVH Prefix only from a directory.It should not select file names beginning with NVHE from the same directory.How can I do that?

I have tried certain things.They are as follows.They are

```
//This will store all file names beginning with NVH prefix and NVHE prefix in array
string[] files11 = Directory.GetFiles(moduleDir, "NVH*.*")
                                 .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                 .ToArray();

//This will store all file names beginning with NVHE prefix in array only
string[] files12 = Directory.GetFiles(moduleDir, "NVHE*.*")
                          .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                 .ToArray();
```

Now I want file names beginning with NVH only,not NVHE.How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles` [does not support regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The search string to match against the names of files in path. This
>   parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard
>   (* and ?) characters (see Remarks), but doesn't support regular
>   expressions.

In alternative you can use the [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(moduleDir)
         .Select(Path.GetFileName)
         .Where(file=>file.StartsWith("NVH") && !file.StartsWith("NVHE"));
```

If you want to preserve the files full path:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(moduleDir)
         .Where(path=>
            {
               var file = Path.GetFileName(path);
               return file.StartsWith("NVH") && !file.StartsWith("NVHE")
            });
```

You can also use your existing code and filter the first collection in this way:

```
var result = files11.Except(files12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well as you are using LINQ already why not add in a `Where` to filter...

```
string[] files11 = Directory.GetFiles(moduleDir, "NVH*.*")//get all files starting with NVH
                             .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))//convert the full paths to filenames only (inc. extensions)
                             .Where(path => !path.StartsWith("NVHE"))//filter out files that start with NVHE
                             .ToArray();
```

It is important to note that the `Where` clause must go after the path conversion (i.e. the `Select` part), otherwise it will try to match the start of the full file path (e.g. `"C:\..."`)

Answer (score 1):

You could add:

```
.Where(path => !path.StartsWith("NVHE"))


string[] files11 = Directory.GetFiles(moduleDir, "NVH*.*")
                             .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                             .Where(path => !path.StartsWith("NVHE"))
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd use ... path.StartsWith("NVHE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) since files are not case-sensitive on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

AND

```
 files11 = files11.Except(files12).ToArray();
```